# host parameter in mysqli_connect() for online website

Tags: php, mysqli, connection

I'm a beginner in PHP development.
In my local station, I use xampp to host my project and use localhost to set up my host parameter. But now that I have uploaded my project in a host server, it gives an error:

```
failed to connect to my sql: Access denied for user 'irdnir_harf'@'localhost' to database 'irdnir_harf'
```

What should I set for it?

Comment: It probably will be `localhost` too, but username won't be `irdnir_harf`. If not, try to put there an IP address of your server.

Comment: This is a typical question that your hosting provider has to answer.

Comment: if u are using free domain then all the dettail will be provide there. everything will be changed. localhost user and password.if u are provided then your provider will know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_connect()` has the following syntax:

`mysqli_connect(hostname, username, password, database)` where hostname is localhost usually.

Make sure your username and password are correct. If not set otherwise, use `root` as your username and leave blank for password.